# Не нажимается кнопка PhantomJS

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

```
pjs.Navigate().GoToUrl("");
        var login =  pjs.FindElementByName("main_login");
        var password = pjs.FindElementByName("main_password");
        var btn = pjs.FindElementByClassName("submit");

        login.SendKeys("***");
        password.SendKeys("***");

        btn.Click();
```

Пишет то , что истекло время ожидания

Comment: Где сама ошибка ? текст и номер исключения ?

Comment: WebExecpiton : истекло время ожидания

Comment: Сейчас пробую и всё получается , почему вчера не работало не понимаю

Comment: @Digital Core теперь опять все не работает +  InnerException {"Время ожидания операции истекло"} System.Exception {System.Net.WebException}

Comment: Теперь опять все работает